# CSS table:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) not working

Tags: css

This is my site https://www.lemeilleuravis.com/nikon-s7000-test/

This is the code that should be working but for some reason doesn't:

```
table:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1):before {
    content: "✓";
    color: green;
    font-size: 200%;
    float: left;
}

table:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1):before {
    content: "";
    font-size: 200%;
    float: left;
}

table:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) {
background:green;
}

table:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) {
background:red
}
```

I did some tests with table:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1):before on w3schools tryit and it was working so there's something wrong with my site that's making it not work.

This is the first Table with text replaced with xxx to save space

```
    <table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="302">xxx

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT: I found the solution, I ended up using nth-of-type instead of nth-child and it worked.

Comment: Show us some of your html.

Answer (score 0):

Check your markup.  My assumption here is that there is another element before the first table.  Cant check your page as Im on mobile.  Try it on codepen or jsfiddle.  Just use the table markup and css to see if the issue still persists.

**EDIT**
You have more other elements in the container other than the table itself.  You either wrap the tables in its own container in order for nth-child to work, or assign a class for the table.

Comment: it actually works with :first-of-type and last-of-type so I dont think there's another table in there. The reason I want to use odd and even tables isto make it more versatile if I ever need it in the future. And it works on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/782cryu4/1/

Comment: Im not saying there is another table. Maybe there is another element, div or span.  Maybe you can port it to codepen so we can assess it better

Comment: here's the codepen, https://codepen.io/GK14/pen/PjKxwZ, I've actually narrowed it down to just table:nth-child(1) not working alone. Still no idea why.

Comment: My assumption is correct.  The reason why the jsfiddle was working is because it only contained the table markup.  Nothing else.  nth-of-type works because you are targeting the table type.  `table:nth-child(1)` means  you are targeting the first element which is a table.

Answer (score 0):

Your color for the checkmark is the same as for the background, so it won't be visible. Try this:

```css
td:nth-child(1):before {
    content: "✓";
    color: white;
    font-size: 200%;
    float: left;
}

td:nth-child(2):before {
    content: "";
    font-size: 200%;
    float: left;
}

td:nth-child(1) {
background:green;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
background:red
}
```

```html
    <table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="302">xxx

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
<td width="302">xxx</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```